# Query quotes in mysql command

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a list of heights such as 6'6" in that format, how would I query that?

What I have right which doesn't work

```
SELECT Height, Weight FROM `students` WHERE Height = (6\'6\") AND Weight >= 200;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Height, Weight FROM students WHERE Height = "6'6\"" AND Weight >= 200;
```

You still need a double quote since they are **string**

Comment: Is that a double-quote after the first back-slash, or is that two single-quotes?

Comment: @JohnSimpson that is double quote.. never use single quote to prevent unwanted error. I just noticed used of double quote - edited.. thanks

Comment: I see now.  You are escaping the double-quote in six inches.  Thanks.